# How to clean up obsolete rewritten commits in git after a git-filter-branch

Tags: git, github

I needed to remove a couple of obsolete files from the git history, so I followed the approach of using "git filter-branch ..." as suggested in various questions and in the git manual. After running the command, I now see the all rewritten commits in my "git log", so instead of the original 10 commits, I now have around 30 commits (after removing 3 files).

I tried the suggestions provided in various answers to remove the ".git/refs/originals" and then "git reflog expire..." and "git gc --aggressive --prune" etc. but I still have 30 commits. I also tried the suggestion of cloning my repository into a new one, and the new one has 30 commits as well. I also pushed to github and now that has 30 commits.

Is there anything I am missing to get rid of the overwritten commits (without doing a rebase operation). My goal is to only get rid of the "duplicate" commits, not to squash commits.

Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

Exactly what commands did you run?  It's probably best to make a fresh clone of this repo and try again.  There is a guide on [help.github](http://help.github.com/removing-sensitive-data/) that might help.

Comment: The github link commands are exactly what I used. However when I do a "git log" it shows me the original commits and the new rewritten ones. Running the purge and clean commands in the github link did not erase those old commits. A push to github copied all those old commits to github. So in all repo I now have the old commits too. I tried cloning a new repo but it still brings in the old commits.

Comment: Could you email support@github.com with more details... what repo and a session dump of the commands your running would be great.

Answer (score 0):

You can also try rebase -i --preserve-merges or script git cherry-pick --no-commit to do what you want.

Hope this helps

Comment: I am specifically not wanting to hand code rebase commands as I will have to cherry pick all original commits, go through re-merge conflicts etc. All I want is a way to erase the old commits that were rewritten.

Comment: The old commits can be forgotten by running git gc after setting the expire time to 0. Once all references to the old commits are removed, those objects will be garbage collected.